# How to resolve screens from the Conductor

Tags: mvvm, caliburn.micro

What is the correct method for resolving screens/viewmodels that I wish to display with `Caliburn.Micro`?

Previously I have been using an `IWidgetConductor` which maintains a collection of `IWidget` objects (which are basically my viewmodels) and I query to obtain the screen/viewmodel I wish to then activate.

```
namespace App
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using App.ViewModels;

    public enum WidgetType
    {
        WidgetA,
        WidgetB,
        WidgetC,
    }

    public interface IWidgetMetaData
    {
        WidgetType WidgetType { get; }
    }

    public class WidgetConductor
    {
        private readonly IEnumerable<Lazy<IWidget, IWidgetMetaData>> widgets;

        private readonly DialogViewModel dialogViewModel;

        public WidgetConductor(IEnumerable<Lazy<IWidget, IWidgetMetaData>> widgets, DialogViewModel dialogViewModel)
        {
            this.widgets = widgets;
            this.dialogViewModel = dialogViewModel;
        }

        public IWidget GetWidget(WidgetType widgetType)
        {
            var lazy = this.widgets.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Metadata.WidgetType == widgetType);
            return lazy == null ? null : lazy.Value;
        }

        public object GetWidgetAsDialog(WidgetType widgetType)
        {
            return this.dialogViewModel.ShowDialog(this.GetWidget(widgetType));
        }
    }
}
```

I register my `Widget`s with my IoC container (Autofac) as such:

```
            builder.RegisterType<WidgetConductor>()
                   .AsSelf()
                   .SingleInstance();
            builder.RegisterMetadataRegistrationSources();
            builder.Register(e => new StatusBarViewModel(e.Resolve<EventAggregator>()))
                   .As<IWidget>()
                   .WithMetadata<IWidgetMetaData>(e => e.For(m => m.WidgetType, WidgetType.StatusBarViewModel));
```

The `WidgetConductor` is passed to the `Shell` viewmodel via its constructor.

A `display screen` event may be published somewhere in my app using the `EventAggregator`, and from the event handling object I query the `WidgetConductor` for the desired `Widget` before passing it to `ActivateItem`:

```
var widget = this.widgetConductor.GetWidget(WidgetType.StatusBarViewModel);
ActivateItem(widget);
```

I feel as though I am bypassing the `Conductor` provided by `Caliburn.Micro` though.  Is there a way of achieving the same result using the `Conductor`?

Answer (score 0):

ShellViewModel inherits `Conductor<Lazy<IWidget, IWidgetMetaData>>.Collection.OneActive` or AllActive.  OneActive allows for 1 viewmodel at a time, AllActive allows for all of them to be active (MDI for example).

You now have access to a property called Items, which in your case is BindableCollection>() (under the covers a ObserableCollection() but with AddRange(object x).  Through normal enumeration on your "ShellViewModel" constructor you can import the IWidget(s), as you have done already with your custom conductor..  .

Then you can either populate a menu or items control...

using a `<ItemsControl x:Name="Items" />` can show the Widgets already in the collection (styled up of course) then using `<ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem" />` and some activation code based the item in question call ActivateItem(SomeWidget), on click of some sort...

reference: https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/blob/master/samples/Caliburn.Micro.HelloScreens/Caliburn.Micro.HelloScreens/

http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/

note: the reference example uses MEF as the IoC Container and is Silverlight implemented, close strategy is slightly different for WPF. AutoFac should be just fine.

hth,

Morgan

Comment: If I inherit from `Conductor<Lazy<IWidget, IWidgetMetaData>>.Collection.OneActive` the `ActivateItem()` expects a `Lazy<IWidget, IWidgetMetaData>` object rather than an `IWidget` for which a view does not exist. Do I need to override `ActivateItem` or something?

Comment: Yes an override might necessary... Which is completely understandable since you using extra Metadata to describe your Widgets.  Another possibility is that you might need to simplify slightly since you were going the extra mile.

Comment: Does IWidget have IScreen as an inherited interface? Or Does your widget inherit Screen, IWidget?

Comment: `SomeWidget : Screen, IWidget` is the route I have gone down.

Comment: Then you should be able to use Conductor<IWidget> without issue, and Items.AddRange(widgets) from your IEnumerable in you your constructor of your shell or main view, viewmodel.

Comment: I can do that, however I then do not have lazy loading on my widgets.

Comment: this is true, You will more than likely have to play with the overload of ActivateItem which can be done to do custom loading.  Reference: https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/blob/master/samples/Caliburn.Micro.HelloScreens/Caliburn.Micro.HelloScreens/Shell/DialogConductorViewModel.cs